# Use JavaScript to style a link by changing its class attribute

Tags: javascript

Edit: I suspect the problem has to do that since all my # anchors are on the same page, unless I reload the page, JavaScript just doesn't know about my clicks on the link. I don't know how to solve this problem though...:(

I'm trying to make a clicked link stay blue if the section it points to is shown. This is the code (I put the Javascript code just before the closing body tag as suggested by [this tutorial](http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/javascript-forum/155444-quick-tip-how-make-active-links.html)).

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
```

JavaScript

```
links = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0; i<links.length;i++) {
   if(links[i].href == window.location.hash) {
   links[i].className = "active";
    }
}
```

CSS

```
a.active {
    color:blue;
}
```

However it does not seem to work. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: do you get an javascript error on the page?

Comment: Add `console.log(links[i].href+" "+window.location.hash)` inside your loop but outside the `if` and see what you get.

Comment: Please post your real HTML. The markup you did post isn't even close to valid. The `<a>` tags are left unclosed with `>`

Comment: there are no javascript errors; how do I check the console log? Yes, I just corrected my code; thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The console log says http://127.0.0.1/application/home.html#section1 http://127.0.0.1/application/home.html#section2 http://127.0.0.1/application/home.html#section3

Answer (score 3):

Your anchor tags aren't closed, make sure they look like this:

```
<a href="#section1">Link Text</a>
```

Notice the closing `"` and `>` that your code is missing.

Also, did you wrap the JavaScript code in a `<script>` block?

```
  <script>
    all of your javascript inside of this script block
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks; I'm a really lousy coder:( Yes, the code is wrapped in a <script> block...

Answer (score 2):

Your href may be absolute in that case, not just hashes:

```
   if(links[i].href == window.location.hash)
```

Comment: I changed my code to if(links[i].href == "http://"+window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname); but it doesn't help any either...

Comment: why not just: if(links[i].href == window.location.href) ?

Comment: Yes, I did just that too; but it's not helping. I noticed that when the page first loads, the console indicates every window.location.href of links[i] is something.com/index.html. When I click on a link, the window.location.href doesn't get changed. However, if I say click on the link that points to #section2 and hit the reload button, window.loacation.href for all links[i] become something.com/index.html#section2, and the section2 link becomes blue too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to put the script inside a function, link it in the header and then call it on load.

```
function f(){
  var links = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("a");

  for(i=0; i<links.length;i++) {
     if(links[i].href == window.location.hash) {
     links[i].className = "active";
      }
  }
}
```

`<body onload="f()">`

Also note the `var links = ...` Meaning a declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but It doesn't work either. Would you mind reading a comment I wrote to fmgp? I think that's what's causing the problem...